# proftpd user rights

Tags: linux, security, ftp, permissions

I have a ftp user chrooted to a sub directory of another user which can read and write but the main user needs to be able to edit the files also

like this:

/user1/

/user1/user2/

how can I get this working in proftpd?

since its an www directory also it has to be secure also (no write for apache user)

Comment: you're not too specific, and the way you're describing your question tells there's no good solution for your problem. it's more like 'please someone do my job' question than a short question - short answer - which this site is mainly about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a group, add the two users to it and make this directory owned by this group and writable, like this:

```
addgroup ftpeditors
adduser user1 ftpeditors
adduser user2 ftpeditors
chgrp ftpeditors /user1/user2
chmod g+w /user1/user2
```

Comment: Either put user1 and user2 using the ftpeditors group as their primary group, or make /user1/user2 group-sticky, and you have a winner.

Comment: you can also do newgrp ftpeditors before creating any files.